# I want to write an OCMock unit test for the button and the method below. How do I write it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ocmock

How do I write an OCMock unit test for the button and the method below

```
//This method displays the UIAlertView when Call Security button is pressed. 
-(void) displayAlertView
{
     UIAlertView *callAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Security" message:@"(000)-000-0000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
     [callAlert show];
     if([[callAlert buttonTitleAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"Call"])
     {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://0000000000"]];
     }
}
//This Button calls the above method.
-(IBAction)callSecurityButton 
{
     [self displayAlertView];
}
```

I have implemented this so far, its giving me this error:

> OCMockObject[UIAlertView]: expected method was not invoked: show:

This is the test case I have written

```
-(void)testDisplayAlertView
{
    OCMockObject *UIAlertViewMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIAlertView class]];
    [[UIAlertViewMock expect] show];
    [self.shuttleHelpViewController displayAlertView];
    [UIAlertViewMock verify];
}
```

I have implemented this so far, its giving me this error:

> OCMockObject[UIAlertView]: expected method was not invoked: show:

Comment: How far have you managed to get?

Comment: I have implemented this so far, its giving me this error: OCMockObject[UIAlertView]: expected method was not invoked: show:-                                      This is the test case i have written -(void)testDisplayAlertView
{
    OCMockObject *UIAlertViewMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIAlertView class]];
    [[UIAlertViewMock expect] show];
    
    [self.shuttleHelpViewController displayAlertView];
    [UIAlertViewMock verify];
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mock object and object created inside method is not same. Should be something like this:

```
//This method displays the UIAlertView when Call Security button is pressed. 
-(void)displayAlertView:(UIAlertView *)callAlert
{
    [callAlert show];
    if([[callAlert buttonTitleAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"Call"])
    {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://0000000000"]];
    }
}

//This Button calls the above method.
-(IBAction)callSecurityButton 
{
    UIAlertView *callAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Security" message:@"(000)-000-0000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
    [self displayAlertView:callAlert];
}
```

And test method:

```
-(void)testDisplayAlertView
{
    OCMockObject *UIAlertViewMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIAlertView class]];
    [[UIAlertViewMock expect] show];
    [self.shuttleHelpViewController displayAlertView:UIAlertViewMock];
    [UIAlertViewMock verify];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AntonPalich for the reply. I have implemented this.  OCMockObject *blah = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[UIAlertView class]];
    OCMockObject *UIAlertViewMock = [[[blah stub] andReturn:[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Security" message:@"(000)-000-0000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil]] initWithTitle:@"Call Security" message:@"(000)-000-0000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
    [[UIAlertViewMock expect] show];
    [self.shuttleHelpViewController displayAlertView];
    [UIAlertViewMock verify];

Comment: Thanks @Abizem for editing. recently joined so didn't know how to do the stuff.